# JQuery sustituir distintos elementos con nombre variable

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy preparando una funcion en la que necesito crear elementos (array, canvas, chart.js) con nombre variable; o sea, que se crea segun el contenido de una variable. ¿como puedo obtener los distintos nombres de elementos (con nombre variable)?

El codigo Javascript es

```js
var ano = "<?php echo $ano;?>"
var ano_ant = "<?php echo $ano_ant;?>"
var ctx_gp001 = document.getElementById("graficorut001");
var grafico_contrut = new Chart(ctx_gp001, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
  labels : <?=json_encode(array_values($meses_graph));?>,
        datasets: [{
      type: 'line',
            label: ano,
            data :<?=json_encode(array_values($datos_graph001));?>,
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'],
            borderColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,1)'],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,0.4)'],
            borderWidth: 1
        }, {
            label: ano_ant,
            type: 'line',
            data: <?=json_encode(array_values($datos_graph_old001));?>,
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#71B37C',
            backgroundColor: '#71B37C',
            pointBorderColor: '#71B37C',
            pointBackgroundColor: '#71B37C',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#71B37C',
            pointHoverBorderColor: '#71B37C'
        }]
    },
    options: {
  responsive: true,        
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<?php
echo "<div align='center'><canvas id='graficorut".$cod."' name='graficorut".$cod."' width='280vw' 
?>
```

Lo que necesito es sustituir todo lo que tenga `001` por el valor que viene de la variable `$cod`. En este caso `ctx_gp001`, `graficorut001` y `$datos_grpah001`.
Lo que quiero evitar es crear el mismo codigo javascript para los 10 graficos que tengo que crear en la misma pagina.

```js
var ctx_gp002 = document.getElementById("graficorut002");
var grafico_contrut = new Chart(ctx_gp002, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
  labels : <?=json_encode(array_values($meses_graph));?>,
        datasets: [{
      type: 'line',
            label: ano,
            data :<?=json_encode(array_values($datos_graph002));?>,
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'],
            borderColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,1)'],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,0.4)'],
            borderWidth: 1
        }, {
            label: ano_ant,
            type: 'line',
            data: <?=json_encode(array_values($datos_graph_old002));?>,
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#71B37C',
            backgroundColor: '#71B37C',
            pointBorderColor: '#71B37C',
            pointBackgroundColor: '#71B37C',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#71B37C',
            pointHoverBorderColor: '#71B37C'
        }]
    },
    options: {
  responsive: true,        
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Pues yo no entendí el punto de reemplazar los 001 por lo que tenga $cod si al final ya lo estás haciendo en tu código. ¿Puedes explicar mejor tu problema o con otro ejemplo más claro?

Comment: No queda muy claro lo que dices, pero creo que la función eval que está disponible para PHP y javascript, te solucionará el problema, ya que puedes generar nombres de variables a partir de otras variables, en el caso de ctx_gp001 por ejemplo, para el resto, simplemente usa <?=$cod?> dónde debas desde PHP. De todas formas no es un sistema muy recomendable.

Comment: Buenas. Creo que no me explique bien. Tengo que crear 10 graficos (ctx_gp001, ctx_gp002, ctx_gp003, .. hasta ctx_gp010).  Asimismo, tengo 10 elementos (graficorut001, graficorut002, graficorut003, ... hasta graficorut010) y los mismo para el origen de los datos ($datos_graph001, $datos_graph002, .. $datos_graph010). Lo que quiero es tener una única secuencia en javascript que me valga para los 10 graficos, ...